# A Hash Link should be indexed and crawled

Tags: googlebot, web-crawlers

I am building my TOC manually by specifying the anchor and build my bullet list.

The links are shown as `https://example.com/posturl#test1`

Do you think these Hash links should be crawled and indexed or it should be `no index` `no follow`

Comment: Is the content at `#test` already part of the larger page or is it content loaded by JavaScript when the link is clicked?

Comment: Yes, it's a part of a larger page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the reason you have those URL's with hashes is, you're navigating to a section down the page. Thus, despite what's in the anchor, it's just a navigation tool.

Google doesn't follow whatever comes after a hash in the URL. Thus, your link, "https://example.com/posturl#test1" will still be seen as the endpoint: "https://example.com/posturl".

See a similar answer in this [Search Console help query](https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/27227839?hl=en). To make one thing clear in there, Google does index all the content on that page; it just doesn't index the version of the URL with the hash, only the regular URL.

Here's another resource from a [webmaster hangout](https://www.deepcrawl.com/blog/news/google-webmaster-hangout-notes-may-1st-2018/). Concensus: "Google doesn’t index URLs with a hash separately."

Thus, you do not need to noindex or nofollow these links, or to do anything for this, really. They will be ignored, and your original URL will be indexed.

Comment: Thank you so much @henry for your usual support, regarding the caching issue do you recommend a specific plugin to enhance site performance

Comment: You're very welcome, @MohamedEl-QassasMVP. I don't have one to recommend, unfortunately, so you'd have to do some research. If your site is hosted on WP Engine, for example, you don't even need one, since they optimize things on the backend for you. Otherwise, do some research, make a list, install a couple, see which one works best with your current setup.