# add the same internal link multiple times in the same article

Tags: google-search, links, backlinks

Is there any SEO negative effect if I used the same internal link multiple times in different contexts in the same article.

**Ex:**

> you should configure [webmaster](https://#) to be able to crawl and indexing
>   your site, .... .. ... ...
>   ....
>   ...
>   to do that you should check [How to configure google web master](https://#)

The first and second link is the same URL, is there any issue to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no negative SEO effect of linking multiple times from one page to another. However, there is no positive effect either, so do it only if it makes sense for your users.

In extreme cases, like where the amount of links on a page is over 150 or so, spiders will stop crawling the links on that page. But it seems from your post that you'd have several links to the same article, not hundreds.

If you're concerned about it, you can `rel="nofollow"` some or most of them. Just remember to leave the most prominent one as a followed link, because you do want to have discoverable pages on related topics.

Think of it this way. A site can link to the same page from the nav, the footer, an aside for whatever reason, and in an article. That's four links on a page, leading to the same endpoint. No harm done, as long as the user benefits.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, The first and second link is the same URL for an internal link not an external link so I should do it nofollow!

Comment: Regarding this point *f you're concerned about it, you can rel="nofollow" some or most of them. Just remember to leave the most prominent one as a followed link, because you do want to have discoverable pages on related topics.* could you please elaborate more on this point!

Comment: Sure, @MohamedEl-QassasMVP. Basically, say you have two links on your page1 to the same page2. You want search engines to follow the link to page2, so they make the connection and crawl the other page. But you don't want them to visit it twice. You would leave the first link as a follow link, and place the nofollow tag on the second link. Crawlers will visit the first link and skip the second. Don't nofollow all of them - leave one for them to follow!

Comment: I am sorry I didn't get your point!

Comment: And What about external links? I am sorry but I am confused!

Comment: Let me give you another example and please confirm, If I mentioned the same link multiple times on the same page I should let only the link dofollow for only one time and other references to the same link should be no follow Is it correct?

Comment: Regarding external links, I should only dofollow the links form the high authority domain, right?

Comment: Well, the nofollow thing, I recommended as just one thing you can do. It's not mandatory, if you don't do it for internal links it'll still be fine. But you're correct in your example. For outbound links, only nofollow paid/advertising links or blog comments or links for sites you aren't sure you wanna pass authority to for some reason. For inbound links, not much you can do, it's up to the webmaster of the other website.

Comment: So it's preferred to at least has one defllow external link for high authority and trusted domain per post, right?

Comment: Could you please check https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/128939/a-hash-link-should-be-indexed-and-crawled and this https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/128944/google-search-console-reports-mobile-friendly-errors-after-enabling-wordpress-ca

Comment: Well, for the follow links, you can leave as many as you want. If you have an article that points to three websites where you trust the info, and also to one website that paid you for a banner advertisement, leave the three as-is and nofollow the ad. I'll take a look at your other links shortly.