# Google Search Console reports mobile friendly errors after enabling WordPress caching plugin

Tags: google-search-console, googlebot, mobile, cache, mobile-friendly-tool

I tried to test my site in the google webmaster, I got Mobile usability issue
But when I exclude the Googlebot in my cache plugin it's working properly!

The speed is important so I am trying to send the cached version to crawl but this is affected the crawl result and I get mobile usability issue!!

[image]

---

**[Edit]**

- Type of cache is Page Cache.
- Powered by what? a 3rd party plugin in Wordpress to optimize the site performance.
- What specific errors are in "Page is not mobile-friendly"?
  In the test live screenshot, the page is not loaded properly as shown below

[image]

I got these mobile errors

[image]

Although it's working outside console properly when I use this tool https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly

[image]

Comment: What type of cache?   Powered by what?  Are you talking about a CDN, a memory cache, or what?   What specific errors are in "Page is not mobile friendly"?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller the question has been updated with more details, could you please reopen it? Thanks for your support

Comment: What WordPress theme do you use?  How does it handle mobile?   Different WordPress themes do it differently.  Some do user agent detection and some are responsive.  My guess is that you use one that does user agent detection based on what is happening here.

Comment: I am using colormag, I got this issue after installing the optimizer plugin

Comment: Different rendering engines and page speed testers can get different results, even in the Google universe, because they're different tools that handle code differently. That said, it sounds like this particular plugin is not playing nice with the theme, or else the hosting. What website host do you use? I would recommend trying different WP optimization plugins and seeing if they work better with Googlebot/GSC.